# Apple rejecting External Testing request because safari opens when app launches?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to test my app on test flight using external testing. I uploaded my build but Apple rejected it. Here is there message:

"Design Preamble

We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:

- Upon launching the app, a web page in mobile Safari opens first, then returns to the app. The user should be able to use the app immediately upon launch."

I've already tried the app on my phone before uploading it and it never opened Safari when it launches. I also used the same build for internal testing and tested on my phone again and it worked. It always shows the launch screen first then shows the main storyboard.

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install of your app on your own device?

Comment: By that do you mean uninstalling and installing again?

Comment: Yes. Delete and do a fresh install of the test build you sent to Apple.

Comment: Oh. its freezing on the launch screen. I dont know what to do!! Its working perfectly on the simulator however.

Comment: Nevermind. I did a "Clean" and it worked on my device. Safari didnt open so i still dont know what the problem is.

Comment: So, the app did have that behavior when they tested. If you didn't code that behavior, then it must be one of the external libraries you have in your project/app. Check those. The problem reminds me of an old behavior install tracking systems introduced some years ago.

Comment: Well I tried that now and everytime I remove one of the librairies I get errors and ruins everything. I don't think that the librairies are the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what the problem was. My certificate was expired and I had to renew it. When I uploaded the build again it got accepted!

Hope this makes sense somehow